# Schema Reference For JasperReports Barcode Component

Tags: jasper-reports

Does anybody here knew where can I download the schema references for the barcode component of Jasper Reports?

I am thinking of using either the `Barbecue` or `BarcodeForJ` component but my problem is, I cannot find the schema for both component.

I have tried guessing this:  I wanted to increase the Font Size of the human readable component.

```xml
<c:Code39 hrSize="10">
    <c:codeExpression><![CDATA["TESTING"]]></c:codeExpression>
</c:Code39>
```

But is says it cannot find the attribute for the element `c:Code39`.  From where can I download this?

When I download JasperReports, I saw the schema reference for the Jasper Library but not with its component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but reading the source would lead me to believe this should work.

What you will want to do is define a style for your sibling `reportElement`.

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement style="Barcode" x="130" y="250" width="400" height="30"/>
    <c:Code39>
        <c:codeExpression><![CDATA["TESTING"]]></c:codeExpression>
    </c:Code39>
</componentElement>
```

Where the `Barcode style` definition's font properties are propagated to [Barcode4j's](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.0/symbol-code39.html) `font-name` and `font-size` properties.

```
<style name="Barcode" isDefault="false" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="10"/>
```

Take a look at `AbstractBarcodeEvaluator.setBaseAttributes()` method found [here](http://jasperforge.org/scm/viewvc.php/tags/jr-3-7-4/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/components/barcode4j/AbstractBarcodeEvaluator.java?root=jasperreports&view=markup).

Comment: Thanks thanks.. That did the trick.. You saved my life =).  I have been studying JasperReports for days now, all I can say is that its very powerful but its kinda lack a good project documentation.  I look at the JasperReport Site and I notice that the schema reference for the barcode component is still to come. Anyways, thanks a lot sir!

Comment: @Mark Estrada - No problem at all.. I was in your shoes about 3 months ago. I spent a lot of time going through the source code, and there are still things that cause me to sit back and scratch my head. One thing I can recommend, is to download iReport from the JasperForge site until you get a really good handle of the markup structure.