# Print Invoice ID as barcode

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, openbravo

I am building a custom invoice for my Openbravo POS installation, Everything works well but on the area that it should show the barcode of the invoice ID it only show's it in numbers(text)

here is the code in my report file

```
<imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[com.openbravo.pos.util.BarcodeImage.getBarcodeEAN13($F{TICKET}.printId())]]></imageExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Barcode4J in my jasper reports and it works well. Moreover, iReports does already include its jar, so you can just drag-n-drop the barcode component on the palette. If you're not using iReport to design the jrxml, here it is a question about this library: [Barcode4J-StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612910/jasperreports-barcode-generation-with-barcode4j-library-depencies) ,

and here it is an overview :[Barcode4J Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/barcode4j/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

EAN13 only accept 12 digit number, any barcode less than 12 digit
will appear as numeric value in abox